# Catch error and log as if it was not caught

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm not sure about the title.

Here is an example :

```
function myFct() {
    throw("error"); // line 2
}

function Foo() {
    try {
        myFct();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error("Error in myFct :"); // line 10
        console.debug(e);
    }
}

Foo();
```

The console will output :

> Error in myFct : (myFile.js:10)
>
> [Details about error] (myFile.js:11)

I want my console to output something like this :

> Error in myFct : (myFile.js:10)
>
> [Details about error] (myFile.js:2)

Note the line 2.
I want the same output as if I was not catching the error.
It would be really useful for debug.

I'm using Chrome Dev Tools but any cross browser solution is a huge plus.

**Note** : feel free to edit the title to better match future searches, I can't find a simple way to explain my wish

Comment: It would interrupt code execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this

```
function myFct() {
throw(new Error().stack); // line 2
}
```

Comment: I used `console.debug(e.stack);` instead, because I don't really throw an error. Thanks for the hint